# Excel Middle mouse button click not scrolling

Tags: excel, vba, mousewheel

I have a workbook that will not let me glide around by *clicking* and holding the middle mouse button.

I've seen a lot of answers and help around basic scrolling with the mouse, but that's working fine in this case. It's when I hold down the button, nothing happens. It works on other spreadsheets I have open at the same time so the problem must be specifically with that workbook.

I seem to remember having the same trouble long ago with a single sheet in a book.

Any ideas? The workbook does have a lot of VBA, but I've been unable to detect any part which would affect this. Could there be something buried in that?

Comment: Have you tried to comment all the VBA to see if it still happens?

Comment: have you freeze or locked rows or/and columns? or something with `FreezePanes` in your code?

Comment: good ideas, but tried both with no luck.

Comment: Can you "scroll" with the down arrow key?  If not, please check the worksheet's `.ScrollArea` property. If this is fixed, then you may not be able to scroll at all.

Answer (score 1):

aha, someone at work figured it out. It happens when you've hidden columns all the way to the end of the sheet. I've unhidden them and am gliding around easy again.

Comment: Same situation worked with me. I have unhidden the columns at the right end of my sheet (it is sad to lose this because it was pretty neat....) and the scroll magically appeared. But I managed a trick here: I hid all of the blank columns to the right of my spreadsheet except for the last one. Spreadsheet is neat and scroll is working!

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I have hidden columns the middle-mouse click does not work, as mentioned by tea_pea. However, if I unhide them and then re-hide them the middle-mouse click works still works. I didn't have to keep the right-most column unhidden.

Using Office365

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).